# verbatim listing with trailing spaces

Tags: verbatim, plain-tex

I'm trying to redefine `\verb` just for fun. It should act like the LaTeX starred version: `\verb<some-char><arbitrary chain of chars not containing it><same char again>` should yield these chars typeset in `\tt` obeying lines and spaces,  where spaces are typeset visible.
I managed to make it work by

```
\def\eol{\hfill\break}
\def\activateas#1#2{%
  \catcode #1 13%
  \lccode`\~ #1%
  \lowercase{\let~#2}%
}
\def\verb#1{%
  \begingroup%
  \def\do##1{\catcode`##1 12}%
  \dospecials%
  \activateas{`#1}\endgroup%
  \activateas{`\^^M}\eol%
\tt}
```

`\dospescials` is a plainTeX macro that does `\do` for `<space><VT><SOH>\{}$&#%~_^`, where you have to provide `\do` yourself;
`\activateas` comes in handy: it gets the character code of something, makes it active and `\let` equals it to the second argument.

**The remaining problem**
Heavily tricky, because TeX is just built such that those are ignored always: How do I take care of trailing spaces (e.g. for typesetting markdown)?

Comment: By the way, what Markdown features require you to use trailing spaces?

Comment: two trailing spaces=linebreak. This is a bad example, a more useful example is the programming language whitespace which would need a definition for ^^I (tab). I just googled that this language existed, it's called an esoteric language.

Comment: I also just learned that markdown syntax is halve disabled in comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing trailing spaces happens very early in TeX (while a line from the file is [being put](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/knuth/tex/tex.pdf#page=15) into TeX's buffer). So this is before the buffer's characters are interpreted according to their catcodes, and even LuaTeX's `process_input_buffer` won't help (as the input buffer doesn't contain the trailing spaces). But with LuaTeX and the `open_read_file` callback, you can achieve what you want, if you put everything in a different file that is `\input`.

For example, you can put the following in `trailing.lua`:

```lua
function trail_space_env(filename)
   -- A table containing a "reader" function for reading a line.
   local ret = {}
   ret.file = io.open(filename)
   ret.reader =
      function(t)
         local line = t.file:read()
         if line == nil then return line end
         -- If line ends with space, append U+200C (ZWNJ)
         return line:gsub(' $', ' ‌')
      end
   return ret
end
callback.register('open_read_file', trail_space_env)
```

(note that the replacement string above is a space followed by the ZWNJ character), the following in your main TeX file (taken from your question; only the last two lines are added):

```
\def\eol{\hfill\break}
\def\activateas#1#2{%
  \catcode #1 13%
  \lccode`\~ #1%
  \lowercase{\let~#2}%
}
\def\verb#1{%
  \begingroup%
  \def\do##1{\catcode`##1 12}%
  \dospecials%
  \activateas{`#1}\endgroup%
  \activateas{`\^^M}\eol%
\tt}

\directlua{dofile('trailing.lua')}
\input everything
```

and the following in `everything.tex`:

```
Regular text.

\verb!
There are two trailing whitespaces here.  
See them?
!

Regular text again.

\bye
```

Then you get:

[image: result]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I guess this is the right idea. I would prefer putting `\char7` (bell) at the end instead of  `%` since this is never needed. And I would refrain from putting this char only on specific lineendings but rather on every line end and leave lines that are nil untouched.

Comment: I sense one flaw to this solution: It changes the input for every file that is input. Is there a solution to make the change in the input routine local while still being able to make use of `\verb` inline?

Comment: @AbraxasKnister I actually changed `%` to U+200C in my last edit. Anyway it's possible to make it local: your `\verb` could set a Lua parameter, which is looked up by the `reader` function before it does the replacement.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to preserve these spaces because they are removed by TeX even before the input is split into tokens and catcodes are assigned. According to *TeX by Topic*, Section 2.2, this was introduced "for the systems with block storage, and it prevents confusion because these spaces are hard to see in an editor."

A workaround would be to use a different character (not having code 32) there which then is rendered as a visible space in the output.

Comment: What a shame... I knew this was the only solution, but are there possibilities for other TeX implementations ie LuaTeX ore eTeX to prevent modifying the input?

Comment: I don't know if LuaTeX provides something, but I'm pretty sure e-TeX handles spaces the same way TeX does